# SVD in least-squares problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-squares, svd

I have the following problem

$$ W^* := \arg\min_W \| WX - Y \|_F $$

where $W^TW = I$ and $I$ is the identity matrix.

Instead of making yet another regression problem we can find optimal orthogonal transformation using singular value decomposition. It turns out that optimal transformation $W^*$ can be expressed via SVD components:
$$X^TY=U\Sigma V^T\text{, singular value decompostion}$$
$$W^*=UV^T$$

I solved this task like a linear regression and get weight in next form
$$W^*=(X^{.T}X)^{-1}(X^{.T}Y)$$
but I can't solve it clearly using  svd, I always have a variable $\Sigma$. I am doing something wrong and I have an error somewhere but I can't understand where ...

Comment: What are the dimensions of $W$, $X$ and $Y$? For example, is $W$ a square matrix or not necessarily so? Are $X$ and $Y$ column vectors?

Comment: Yes, $W$ is square matrix and $X,Y$ is columns vectors

Comment: I have 2 comments. Thinking geometrically, there is always a rotation which takes $X$ to a vector $X'$ such that $X$ and $X'$ have the same norm and $Y = c X'$ for some $c > 0$. Such a rotation is in higher dimensions not unique, but I think any such rotation is optimal. You cannot reduce the error anymore than that, which is the difference in absolute value between the norms of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Another comment, I think the transposes are not where they should be in your equations (unless I am mistaken). Indeed you want to solve for $(WX - Y)X^T = 0$, so that $W = (Y X^T) (X X^T)^{-1}$, assuming $X X^T$ is invertible.

Comment: sorry $X,Y$ also matrices with dimension $m,n$, and W square matrices

Comment: Such information should be included in the question itself.

Comment: I'm not an expert in linear algebra ..

1)I'm not sure, but as I remember the matrix W* will have the best approximation in the Frobenius norm

2)yes we assuming that $XX^T$ is invertible, and we also can rewrite this problem like $||XW-Y||=||Y-XW||->min$, so it doesn't matter because here we calculate norm